# Assign a value to a struct which was declare from other package

Tags: go

Here is my code.
I extract my struct OperatInfo to the struct.go and wanna to use this struct in the main package which in worker.go.

struct.go

```
package batch

type OperatInfo struct {
    eventId string
    hallId string
    userId string
    operating string
    operatingID string
    ip string
}
```

worker.go

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "./kernel/api"
    "./kernel/db"
    "./batch/basic"
    "./batch/struct"
)

var operatInfo batch.OperatInfo

func BatchDeposit(eventId string, userId string, hallId string, operating string, operatingID string, ip string) {
    // I get an error here
    operatInfo.eventId = eventId
    operatInfo.hallId = hallId
    operatInfo.userId = userId
    operatInfo.operating = operating
    operatInfo.operatingID = operatingID
    operatInfo.ip = ip
}
```

I just can't set operatInfo fields.

Any suggestions or tips will helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the fields that starts with an upper case letter are public visible.
To solve your problem you can create getter and setter for each field or rename your fields' struct as follow:

```
type OperatInfo struct {
    EventId string
    HallId string
    UserId string
    Operating string
    OperatingID string
    Ip string
}
```